# Why is my Paint surface method not working?

Tags: java, swing, paint

So for a while overriding the paint method of JComponent has given me trouble and I can never figure out why. I am working on a project that will take a black and white image and paint it on the screen where every pixel in the picture is a 50 x 50 box on the screen obviously some of the painting will be done off screen but that is OK because it will be a 2D top down game with a moving screen. No matter what I have tried, when it runs it never paints anything on the screen and it has nothing to do with my 1:50 logic because when I just tried to make it draw a simple rectangle, it didn't even draw that. So the problem must lie in the paint method but I can't figure out what is wrong. I know it is a lot of code but could someone please let me know what is wrong?
(I know there is a lot of methods that aren't being used yet, just ignore those ones)

This is the Jframe class:

(you must specify the path for the black and white image to draw in this class)

```
`package Code;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

//class that stores all of the painting methods and the GUI methods:
public class Window extends JFrame{

    double WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT;
    JPanel TitlePanel;
    JButton PlayGame, Quit;
    JLabel Title;
    Map DigitizedMap;
    PaintSurface PS;

    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int TilesAcross;
    int TilesDown;

    public Window(){

        WINDOWWIDTH = 1200;
        WINDOWHEIGHT = (Math.floor(WINDOWWIDTH / 50)*0.66) * 50;
        TilesAcross = (int) (WINDOWWIDTH / 50);
        TilesDown = (int) (WINDOWHEIGHT / 50);

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize((int) WINDOWWIDTH, (int) WINDOWHEIGHT);
        this.setTitle("Stealth Client    ||    Version 1.0");

        //all of the code for the user interface will go here:
        //DrawStartInterface(this);

        //creating the digitized verion of the map for the paint method to use:
        MapLoader ML = new MapLoader("C:\\Users\\Greg\\Desktop\\TestMap.png");
        DigitizedMap = ML.ConvertMap();
        PS = new PaintSurface();
        TitlePanel = new JPanel();
        TitlePanel.add(PS, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.add(TitlePanel);

        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setResizable(false);
    }

    private void DrawStartInterface(JFrame f){
        //all of the starting UI:

        TitlePanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        TitlePanel.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);

        Title = new JLabel("STEALTH");
        Title.setForeground(Color.ORANGE);
        Title.setFont(new Font("Calabri", Font.BOLD, 48));
        addItem(TitlePanel, Title, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1);

        PlayGame = new JButton("Play");
        PlayGame.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        PlayGame.setForeground(Color.ORANGE);
        PlayGame.setFont(new Font("Calabri", Font.BOLD, 36));
        PlayGame.addActionListener(new ActionEvent());
        addItem(TitlePanel, PlayGame, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1);

        Quit = new JButton("Quit");
        Quit.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        Quit.setForeground(Color.ORANGE);
        Quit.setFont(new Font("Calabri", Font.BOLD, 36));
        Quit.addActionListener(new ActionEvent());
        addItem(TitlePanel, Quit, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1);

        f.add(TitlePanel);
    }

    private class ActionEvent implements ActionListener{
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
            //which action has been heard:
            if(e.getSource() == PlayGame){
                //plays the game:
                StartGame();
            } else if(e.getSource() == Quit){
                //Quits the game:
                Terminate();
            }
        }

    }

    public void Terminate(){
        //exits the game:

        System.exit(0);
    }

    //Starts the game:
    private void StartGame(){
        TitlePanel.add(PS);
    }

    //The paint Surface class that will be stored in the panel and paint the game:
    class PaintSurface extends JComponent{
        @Override
        public void paint (Graphics g){
            //basic graphics shizel wizel:
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2.drawRect(100, 100, 100, 100);
            render(g2);
            System.out.println("Painted");
        }

        private void render(Graphics2D g2){
            //renders only the squares within a certain distance of the center of the screen:
            int PlayerTileX = (int) Math.ceil((x + (WINDOWWIDTH / 2))/50);      // This is the x tile that the player is in
            int PlayerTileY = (int) Math.ceil((y + (WINDOWHEIGHT / 2))/50);     // this is the y tile that the player is in
            //now we are going through only the tiles around the player and rendering them:
            int XOffset = x - (int) (PlayerTileX - (Math.ceil(TilesAcross / 2)));
            int YOffset = y - (int) (PlayerTileY - (Math.ceil(TilesDown / 2)));
            for (int i = (int) (PlayerTileX - (Math.ceil(TilesAcross / 2))); i < (int) (PlayerTileX + (Math.ceil(TilesAcross / 2))); i++){
                for (int n = (int) (PlayerTileY - (Math.ceil(TilesDown / 2))); n < (int) (PlayerTileY + (Math.ceil(TilesDown / 2))); n++){
                    //this is where only the coorect boxes will be rendered because of the limiting for loops:
                    //The if statement for determining what type of thing it is:
                    if (DigitizedMap.getTile(i, n) == 1){
                        //Rendering the walls:
                        g2.drawRect((int)(((i * 50) % WINDOWWIDTH) - XOffset), (int)(((i * 50) % WINDOWHEIGHT) - YOffset), 50, 50);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //used to add things to panels:
    public void addItem(JPanel p, JComponent c, int x, int y, int width, int height,
            int align /* Defines the spot on the coordinate */) {
        GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gc.gridx = x;
        gc.gridy = y;
        gc.gridwidth = width;
        gc.gridheight = height;
        gc.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);

        switch (align) {
        case 1:
            gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
            break;
        case 2:
            gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
            break;
        case 3:
            gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTH;
            break;
        case 4:
            gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
            break;
        case 5:
            gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
            break;
        }
        p.add(c, gc);
    }

}
`
```

Here is the Starthere class (class that contains the main method):

```
    package Code;

public class StartHere {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Creating the frame:
        final Window Frame = new Window();
    }

}
```

Here is the map class that stores all of the map data:

```
package Code;

public class Map {

    //the Array for all of the codes:
    double Tiles[][];
    int width;
    int height;

    //setters and getters for the width and height:
    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public void setWidth(int width) {
        this.width = width;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(int height) {
        this.height = height;
    }


    //the constructor for the double map:
    public Map(long Width, long Height){
        Tiles = new double[(int) Width][(int) Height];
    }

    //this is where the double array is going to be set:
    public void setTile(int x, int y, double type){
        Tiles[x][y] = type;
    }

    //this gets the given tile code:
    public double getTile(int x, int y){
        return Tiles[x][y];
    }

}
```

And Finally, here is the map loader class that is responsible for loading the map from the image file:

```
package Code;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.ImageObserver;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class MapLoader {

    BufferedImage MapImage;

    public MapLoader(String MapPath){
        //loading the map image from the specified map path:
        try {
            MapImage = ImageIO.read(new File(MapPath));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public Map ConvertMap(){
        Map m = new Map(MapImage.getWidth(), MapImage.getHeight());

        //now to read the individual pixels of the image and determine the code for the map object:
        for(int i = 0; i < MapImage.getWidth(); i++){
            for(int n = 0; n < MapImage.getHeight(); n++){
                if (MapImage.getRGB(i, n) == Color.BLACK.getRGB()){
                    //Black = Wall = 1
                    m.setTile(i, n, 1);
                    System.out.print("1");
                } else {
                    //else it is nothing so White = Space = 0
                    m.setTile(i, n, 0);
                    System.out.print("0");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }

        return m;
    }

}
```

Thank you so much to anyone that helps this has been bugging me for several days and I am out of ideas.

Also here is an example file that I have been using:
[Example File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkQmz.png)

Comment: 1) Always override paintComponent, not paint. Any decent graphics tutorial will tell you this. 2) Always call the super's painting method, `super.paintComponent(...)` if you're overriding that, within your override. 3) Create your code in such a way so that each class can be independently testable and debugable, using small mock classes to help you do this. 4) This way if you run into a bug, you can create and post your [mcve] for us to test and not ask us to go through the entire large program.

Comment: Note that you **never** call `DrawStartInterface(...)`! Side recommendations: Please learn and follow Java naming conventions as doing this will help others to better understand your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your paint method works, but no one can see the PaintSurface object. You have:

```
  PS = new PaintSurface();
  TitlePanel = new JPanel();
  TitlePanel.add(PS, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

You're adding the PS object to the BorderLayout.CENTER position, but TitlePanel doesn't use BorderLayout -- it uses default FlowLayout. Now PaintSurface has a preferred size of 0,0, and since TitlePanel uses FlowLayout, PS will be **very** small.

Solution: set TitlePanel's layout to BorderLayout.

```
  PS = new PaintSurface();
  TitlePanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
  TitlePanel.add(PS, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

This will have the PaintSurface instance fill TitlePanel.

---

Also, as per my comments:

- Always override paintComponent, not paint. Any decent graphics tutorial will tell you this.
- Always call the super's painting method, super.paintComponent(...) if you're overriding that, within your override.
- Create your code in such a way so that each class can be independently testable and debuggable, using small mock classes to help you do this.
- This way if you run into a bug, you can create and post your Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example for us to test and not ask us to go through the entire large program.
- Note that you never call `DrawStartInterface(...)`
- Please learn and follow Java naming conventions as doing this will help others to better understand your code. Field and method names should all start with a lower-case letter while class and interface names should start with an upper-case letter.

Comment: For reference, Java naming conventions: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf

Comment: Also, don't name your class "Window" since you will eventually run into confusion with the java.AWT.Window class, which is a superclass of JFrame. For that matter, try not to name any of your classes the same as existing java classes.